# C++/CLI metadata error when adding methods to children class

Tags: c++-cli

I have a weird problem and can't figure out what's this about.

I have a child class that's .h file is created like this:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Osoba.h"
#include "Lekarz.h"


ref class Pacjent :
    public Osoba
{
    public:
        Pacjent(String ^ imie, String ^ nazwisko, String ^ telefon, String ^ pesel) :
            Osoba(imie, nazwisko, telefon) {
        }
        bool appointVisit(DateTime^ date, Lekarz^ lekarz);
    protected:
        String ^ pesel;
    private:
        int getGender();

};
```

It works exactly as expected when there's no appointVisit method. After adding it I started receiving error LNK2022 saying that metadata in duplicated types.
It works just fine in classes that don't inherit. In inherited classes I cannot get it working properly. What am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: @HansPassant that's the .h file. I am not including any .cpp files so I don't get where's the problem coming from.

Comment: Do you have any tips how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please, include the class `Osoba` too! It is important to keep clean the .h (declaration) and .cpp (implementation) stuff. You may need to clean your project folder:  .vs (folder), *.VC.db (file) and/or try to clean the solution.

Comment: You might need `public` before `ref`.